# problem with software center 12.04

Tags: 12.04, software-center, sudo, crash

I have been using 12.04 in dell vostro since a year.
It was working properly but suddenly the Ubuntu Software Center has started hanging. Now it doesn't open. And every time I try to open it, I have to force quit it. So that I am not able to install the software that I need. What do I do?
And have been suffering with this problem quite a while.
Before posting this,i have read the previous issues in ask ubuntu..tried different versions..,i have killed and updated/removed and re-installed..but none worked..while reinstalling i got this problem in the terminal saying..invalid operation purge..please help me..have been suffering with this for a long time..

Comment: Open a terminal, run `sudo apt-get install software-center` and edit your question to add the output.

Answer (score 0):

At first, open the terminal or press "ctrl+alt+t"
Then type and run following commands in terminal

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

after finishing  the command type following command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then try to open software center
if you face problem further....
then run following command

```
sudo apt-get remove software-center
sudo apt-get autoremove sotware-center
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

if you face further problem with installing of opening software center then ren following command

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

then go to search button on the panel and type "software center"
hope your problem will be solved

best of luck